# Reformat date column while copying using sed

Tags: sed

I need to copy .csv files from one directory to another, and while doing so need to reformat the first column, which is a date column, from 13/04/2012 to 2012-04-13. What is the sed syntax to perform this simple conversion? I am getting awfully confused by the sed stuff I'm reading on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried so far? You could start with something small like this as a test case:

```
echo "13/04/2012;Col2;Col3" | sed -E 's#^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(.*)#\3-\2-\1\4#'

s           = substitution command
#           = start of pattern
^           = start of line
([^/]+)/    = group of all non-/-characters followed by a / (day)
([^/]+)/    = group of all non-/-characters followed by a / (month)
([0-9]+)    = group of at least one digit (year)
(.*)        = rest of line
#           = start of replacement
\3          = backward reference to capture of third group (year)
\2          = backward reference to capture of second group (month)
\1          = backward reference to capture of first group (day)
\4          = backward reference to capture of fourth group (rest of line)
# end of command
```

Comment: `sed` (at least mine/gnu 4.2.1) requires `\+`, not a plain `+`.

Comment: @Kevin : it doesn't, if one uses extended regular expressions (-E)!

Comment: Great answer - does exactly what I want and your explanation of the different groupings is clearer and more concise than anything else I have read on the internet about sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's|^\([0-9]\+\)/\([0-9]\+\)/\([0-9]\+\)|\3-\2-\1|'
```

This starts at the beginning of the line (`^`), records (`\(...\)`) one or more (`\+`) numbers (`[0-9]`), followed by a slash (`/`), a second set followed by another slash, and a third set, and rearranges the recorded sets (`\1,\2,\3`) separated by dashes.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^\(..\).\(..\).\(....\)/\3-\2-\1/' file
```